# How to validate dynamic created data in view model android

Tags: android

I have created one application using mvvm and read data from the json file. From json data i have created Dynamic layout. But don't know how to validate that data in view model

Comment: Share us with some code and json it will help us to understand the situation

Comment: [{
 "id": "firstName",
 "type": "TEXT",
 "text": "First Name"
},
 {
  "id": "middleName",
  "type": "TEXT",
  "text": "Middle Name"
 },
 {
  "id": "lastName",
  "type": "TEXT",
  "text": "Last Name"
 },
 {
  "id": "next1",
  "type": "BUTTON",
  "text": "Next"
 }}

Comment: private fun createButton(jsonObject: JSONObject) {
        var button = Button(this)
        button.text = jsonObject.getString(text)
        button.setTag(jsonObject.getString(id))
        button.layoutParams=layoutParamMargin           // set margin to button
        linearLayout.addView(button)

        button.setOnClickListener {
            // Next button click
            var firstNameEdittext: EditText = linearLayout.findViewWithTag<EditText>(firstName)

Comment: Please help me, How to do validation in viewmodel